# How to calculate the probability p of a binomial distribution using the mean?

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, descriptive-statistics

> You are given following elements about a binomial distribution:
>
> - n = 15
> - $\overline{x} = 2$
>
> What is the value of the probability $p$?

I mean this $p$:

[image]

My guess is: $p = \frac{2}{15}$.

Comment: $x$ doesn't appear anywhere else in your question.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\bar x$ is empirical mean of $x_1,...,x_n$ (i.e. $k$'s in the equation you quote) that follow binomial distribution. Expected value [for binomial distribution is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mean)

$$ E(X) = \mu = np $$

so simple arithmetic shows that

$$ p = \frac{\mu}{n}$$

so if you use $\bar x$ as estimator of $\mu$, than yes, you are right.